# Replacing an outbound soap request body with custom xml

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am using jax-ws and implement a soap handler to patch the outbound requests.
I am swamped for 2 days in soap elements and node elements.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    try {
        if (outbound) {
            SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();

            SOAPPart sp = msg.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope env = sp.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
            NodeList list = body.getElementsByTagName("template");
            if(list.getLength() > 0) {
                Element template = (Element) list.item(0);
                if (template != null) {
                    String newBodyText = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(template.getTextContent());

                    Element bodyElement= XmlUtils.getBodyElement(newBodyText);
                    SOAPElement requestElement = SOAPFactory.newInstance().createElement(bodyElement);
                    body.removeContents();
                    body.insertBefore(requestElement, null);//HERE IS THE EXCEPTION
                    msg.saveChanges();
                    System.out.println("AFTER PATCHING REQUEST :");
                    msg.writeTo(System.out);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The method `XmlUtils.getBodyElement` is the following:

```
public static Element getBodyElement(String fromText) {
    Element result = null;
    String cleanSource = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(fromText).replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");


    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document allDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(cleanSource.getBytes()));
        NodeList list = allDocument.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body");
        if(list.getLength() > 0) {
            Element body = (Element)list.item(0);
            result =  (Element)body.getFirstChild();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the end, when I try to insert the new created `SOAPElement` in the body, I get the following exception:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
```

I am running out of ideas. Do you have any idea what I should do?

Comment: Please refer [add elements to soap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbhw/index.html). In the above code, you are creating a whole new instance of SOAPElement which is causing the problem.

Comment: Before I posted I tried with body.appendChild, body.addChildElement... same. The page you indicate shows how to add node by node. I want to completely substitute the body with another, from a xml.

Comment: Also I tried :  `Element bodyElement= XmlUtils.getBodyElement(newBodyText);
                        Document document = XmlUtils.newDocument();
                        document.importNode(bodyElement, true);


                        body.removeContents();
                        body.addDocument(document);`  No more luck.

Comment: I was about to suggest adding Document to the body :). So what was the result of doing that?

Comment: There is no body when I use `msg.writeTo(System.out);`. I am not sure what is wrong, the `addDocument` or the `importNode` usage.

Comment: Hope you do not have any references to that Document object, once you add it to the SOAPBody. Refer this _Calling this method invalidates the document parameter. The client application should discard all references to this Document and its contents upon calling addDocument. The behavior of an application that continues to use such references is undefined._

Comment: I am just adding it to the body, I don't use it afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154964/discussion-between-gautam-and-joel).